# MSSQL Recurring Transaction Log full. Need to know who causes it

Tags: sql-server, transactions

MSSQL V18.7.1
Transaction log on databases is back-upped every hour.
Size from this databaselog is auto-grow with 128Mb max 5Gb

This runs smoothly but sometimes we do get an error in our application:
'The transaction log for database Borculo is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'

This message we got 8.15AM while on 8.01AM de log-backup was done (and emptied).

I would really like it if I had a script or command to check what caused this exponential growth.

We could backup more often (ever 30 minutes) or change size but the problem is not solved then.
Basically this problem should not occur with the number of transactions we have.

Probably some task is running (in our ERP) which causes this.

This does not happen every day but in the last month this is the 2nd time.

The transaction-log is a back-upped one to get info from. Not the active one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: This is a question better asked on [dba.se], however, with the only question being *"Can anyone point me in the right direction?"* this doesn't have the focus to be on topic there either.

Comment: My question is a script or command to get this information or an example, Think I am in the right place

Comment: If you need a script, then Google/bing/other search engine is your friend, saho. "Give me a script to do *x*" isn't question. As i mentioned, what you are talking about is certainly more on topic of [dba.se], but again you need to make the question on topic for there; *"Can anyone point me in the right direction?"* is not an answerable question. Unless you accept [Google](https://google.com) as an answer?

Comment: Every hour is a long time between log backups. You are better off, for performance if nothing else doing it more frequently. ApexSql have an application that can read log files. Also see undocumented system function `fn_dblog` which can show you who is logging what.

Comment: I have googled all day. ApexSQL I have seen, but very expensive. 
f.e. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3555/read-sql-server-transaction-log-backups-to-find-when-transactions-occurred/   is a nice example but then you have to really search for 'delete'actions. I need to interpret the log so I can see what causes it.  I have now set the backup frequence to 15 minutes

Comment: ApexSql have a trial and I think iirc it gives you some but not all of the log entries. I've used it myself in the past to identify a very similar issue caused by in my case an overnight job with a bad query that was running an update againt 50m rows and filling the log with gigs of transactions - the free version was enough to identify the issue.

Comment: Database Backup strategies should be driven by the Business expectation. Now you have setup your Log Backups to every 15 mins but make sure you make the business aware of the potential risk of losing 14 mins and 59 seconds worth of data. If they are happy losing this much data, then you have done your job, if they say no then you need to find a solution which matches the business expectation and given them options with price tag and let them make the decision, in my view this is when you have done your job right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An hourly transaction log backup means in case of a disaster you could lose up to an hour's worth of data.

It is usually advised to keep you transaction log backups as frequent as possible.

Every 15 mins is usually a good starting point. But if it is a business critical database consider a transaction log backup every minute.

Also why would you limit the size for your transaction log file? If you have more space available on the disk, allow your file to grow if it needs to grow.

It is possible that the transaction log file is getting full because there is some maintenance task running (Index/Statistics maintenance etc) and because the log file is not backed up for an entire hour, the logs doesn't get truncated for and hour and the file reaches 5GB in size. Hence the error message.

Things I would do, to sort this out.

1. Remove the file size limit, or at least increase the limit to allow it to grow bigger than 5 GB.
2. Take transaction Log backups more frequently, maybe every 5 minutes.
3. Set the log file growth increment to at least 1 GB from 128MB (to reduce the number of VLFs)
4. Monitor closely what is running on the server when the log file gets full, it is very likely to be a maintenance task (or maybe a bad hung connection).
5. Instead of setting max limit on the log file size, setup some alerts to inform you when the log file is growing too much, this will allow you to investigate the issue without any interference or even potential downtime for the end users.

Comment: Pretty much what I would suggest also. I would add to check for any correlation between times of large log backups to recently executed agent jobs; capture queries from the procedure cache and write to a table every minute for later perusal. Also, 8GB is miniscule for a Sql Server; My desktop machine I'm sitting at has 16GB, our production SQL Servers are min 64gb, even my phone has more ram...